# Using Cordova with Android. How do I show background Notification?

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I'm trying to show a notification using Android.  The following code does not show anything.  Am I missing something?  No errors are thrown and the code executes but I see no dialogs or anything to indicate a notification.

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
              this.getSystemService(android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 


      Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this.getApplicationContext())
        .setContentTitle("Socket Message Received")
        .setContentText("My Application")
        .setSmallIcon(com.mypackage.app.R.drawable.icon)
        .build();

      mNotificationManager.notify(5, n);
```

Or when I am calling this directly from a Cordova plugin

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
                  cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 


          Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext())
            .setContentTitle("Socket Message Received")
            .setContentText("My Application")
            .setSmallIcon(com.mypackage.app.R.drawable.icon)
            .build();

          mNotificationManager.notify(CM_NOTIFICATION_ID.hashCode(), n);
```

So does anyone have any idea why this would show nothing with no errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
Notification notification;
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    new Intent(context, myactivity.class), 0);

// To support 2.3 os, we use "Notification" class and 3.0+ os will use
// "NotificationCompat.Builder" class.
if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
notification = new Notification(icon, message, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, appname, message,
        contentIntent);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify((int) when, notification);

} else {
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        context);
notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
        .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
        .setContentText(message).build();

notificationManager.notify((int) when , notification);

}
}
```

Hope this helps.This works for me.

Comment: Thanks... this basically worked for me.  I had some issues running it on my device b/c it did not have Notification.Builder on it but somehow it was still running that version.